# nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I'm new to ruby and I'm taking a course on it and got a bit stuck. I'm trying to create a class to represent a vending machine and several classes to represent items within it, which inherit from the vending machine.

Here's the code for the vending machine class and I've included a comment on the line throwing an error:

```
class VendorFood
  @@total_sales = 0
  def initialize(name, price, vending_number)
    @name = name
    @price = price
    @vending_number = vending_number
    @supply = 0
  end

  def stock_item(num)
    @supply += num
  end

  def vend_item
    if @supply >= 1
      @supply -= 1
      self.update_sales(@cost) #getting error here
    end
  end

  def update_sales(cost)
    @@total_sales += cost
  end

  def to_s
    puts "Total Sales: #{@@total_sales}\nName: #{@name}\nPrice: #{@price}\nSupply: #{@supply}"
  end

  attr_reader :name
  attr_writer :name

  attr_reader :price
  attr_writer :price

  attr_reader :vending_number
  attr_writer :vending_number

  def sales
    @@total_sales
  end
end
class CandyBar < VendorFood
  
end
```

So essentially what I'm trying to do is be able to instantiate items without storing an instance of VendorFood. So this works if I remove the problematic line:

```
myBar = CandyBar.new("Hershey", 1.99, 101)
myBar.stock_item(17)
myBar.vend_item
myBar.to_s
```

But I want `vend_item` to then call update sales and increment it by the cost of the item.

This is the exact error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from main.rb:8:in <main>
        2: from /mnt/c/users/price/onedrive/desktop/VendorFood.rb:17:in vend_item
        1: from /mnt/c/users/price/onedrive/desktop/VendorFood.rb:22:in update_sales
/mnt/c/users/price/onedrive/desktop/VendorFood.rb:22:in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you do `self.update_sales(@cost)`, `@cost` is not defined, maybe you wanted to use `@price`?

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. I can't believe it was something that dumb, I've been staring at it for an hour lol

Comment: As an aside `attr_accessor :variable_name` provides both the reader (getter) and the writer (setter) and accepts any number of arguments. e.g. `attr_accessor :name, :price, :vending_number`. Also this is generally placed at the top of the class definition.

Comment: I'll edit it within my file, thanks for the pointers.